# Use Import / Export from SQL Server Management Studio to reduce database size

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database on a production server. The size of database is above 30 GB now. When I export its data using the Import-Export tool in SQL Server Management Studio, the target database filled up with compete data.

But the size of target database reduced dramatically around 50% (i.e. goes to 14 / 15 GB). I tried shrink command to reduce the size but it reduces the database not more than 2 percent.

My process for this import export is as below:

1. Generate scripts for tables/functions/procedures creation from source database
2. Use those scripts on blank target database to create same tables (with constraints), functions and procedures
3. Then disable all constraint on target database
4. Use SQL Server’s Import/Export tool and import data from source to target database
5. After completion of importing of all data, enable all constraints on target database
6. Done

This process make the exact replica of source database. The target database however comes with very small in size when I compare it with the source database.

My question is, can I fully trust this new target database? Can I replace the source database with this target database and use it on production server?

Comment: 30 GB isn't large, I've seen production loads of 8 TB. Anyhow I would not use Import/export to setup a new database. Rather use `DDBC CHECK` and  Backup and Restore with checksum. To create a new environment.

Comment: Also doing backups is hard and you really need to know what you are doing. Thats why you could use [ola hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) solution. You can still make mistakes, but it sure helps using this over something you create yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether 30 Gb is large or small obviously depends on your specific business context, so I'm not sure what Preben is trying to say there. Maybe just having a bit of a boast?

However, I agree that using the wizard to spin up a new copy of the database is an odd approach. It would be much faster and easier to backup the existing production database, and restore it as a new copy.

The target database will be smaller because it will have no fragmentation, and possibly because the recovery setting is different. As the first database is constantly in use over a long period of time, SQL has to find somewhere to put all the new data being created.

As an analogy, think about all the things you have in your home. Things are on shelves, things are in cabinets, some things are just on the floor. Now you go and buy something new, and you have to figure out where to put it. Maybe you have to move some of your old things to find space for the new things. Everything gets spread out.

Then one day you decide to move house. You take all your things, put them in boxes, and move the boxes to the new house. Everything in your new home is organised into a small amount of space, inside the boxes, because you haven't yet started using any of it.

Once you start actually using those things you will have to spread them all around your new home, on shelves, in cabinets, and so on, and they will suddenly be taking up more space. The more things you need to use, the more boxes get unpacked and spread around the room.

Comment: The database is increasing fast. During these days, I reviewed the codes in running scripts. I will remove extra temp data and the software scripts will also be update. This will will give me not more than 5GB free. What I have practically viewed that using import/export (After deleting temp records) will reduce the database size to good position. The points mentioned by @allmhuran are noted but how the trust level on that target database is affecting? In test environment, I applied this and did not found any negative impact on performance. Thanks for your time and guide.

Comment: @NaveedAshraf By "trust level" do you mean the trustworthy flag you can set on a database? If so, it won't have any impact on performance either way.

Comment: No. I mean that can I trust on my target database? Can I use that target database in place of source database on production server? I understand that in future the new target database will also grow, but that will take much time (at least 3 years - estimated).

Comment: I would say the fact that the new database is smaller does not indicate any problem with it. Of course, whether or not it is "trustworthy" really depends on the specific details of your ETL. For example, say the source database used an identtiy column. There's no guarantee that the target database will generate the same identity values unless you set `identity_insert` to on and created them explicitly. But assuming you've already checked all of that in your ETL design, then you should not be worried by the smaller total size of the target.